# Setting new size for printLayout using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

I am trying to create an A0 layout from PyQGIS. I tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```py
from qgis.core import *

manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager() 
layouts_list = manager.printLayouts()
for l in layouts_list:
    l.clear()

layout = QgsPrintLayout(QgsProject.instance())  
layout.setName("TEST")
layout.initializeDefaults()
page = QgsLayoutItemPage(layout)
pageSizes = QgsPageSizeRegistry()
pageSize = pageSizes.find("A0")[0]
orientation = QgsLayoutItemPage.Landscape
valid = page.setPageSize(pageSize.displayName, orientation)
print(valid, page.pageSize().width(), page.pageSize().height(), page.orientation())

manager.addLayout(layout)
```

When I execute this code the layout is created and I get the following message in the console:

True 1189.0 841.0 1. 
True means that the `setPageSize` was a success and the sizes are correct.

But when I open the layout in the interface I always get an A4 page.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Try using the following which uses the [`pageCollection()`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayout.html#a335b0864da1587dfb7f9f903d58c02d6) method to manage the page settings:

```py
layout = QgsPrintLayout(QgsProject.instance())  
layout.setName("TEST")
layout.initializeDefaults()
pc = layout.pageCollection()
pc.pages()[0].setPageSize('A0', QgsLayoutItemPage.Orientation.Landscape)
manager.addLayout(layout)
```

Comment: thank you for this. any idea how to modify 'A0' to be a custom page size in mm? documentation seems to be lacking for setPageSize...

Answer (score 0):

typo : The orientation belongs directly to QgsLayoutItemPage

```
from qgis.core import *
manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager() 
layout = QgsPrintLayout(QgsProject.instance())  
layout.setName("TEST")
layout.initializeDefaults()
pc = layout.pageCollection()
pc.pages()[0].setPageSize('A0', QgsLayoutItemPage.Landscape)
manager.addLayout(layout)
```

This code works.

Comment: I notices that the method pageCollection is not described in the documentation (https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.4/core/QgsPrintLayout.html#qgis.core.QgsPrintLayout.atlas).